# Practical reasons for 200 limit of AWS resources in CF templates

Tags: microservices, serverless, aws-cloudformation

Not sure I get it. If my service layer is completely maintainable, indepedent services and very easy to maintain taking only a few minutes to deploy and has no bugs, AWS still won't let me deploy it if it uses 201 resources. This seems like dogma or am I wrong?

Comment: Service limits are usually nor hard limit s, but can be raised with a support request. Most likely this is either to protect their SLA or to stop you from a stupid common behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 200 limit can be raised, however this is a grinding process that can take months. You work through customer support to get "elevated" as a client to more AWS privileges.

Resources:
- Worked under a company that specifically ran into this problem, took 8 months before that limit was lifted.

Comment: Gee, 8 months. There must be some really weird effects larger amount of resources have